# How to remove some key contain a string from SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, key, sharedpreferences

My Android SharedPreferences is:

key,value

jhon,usa

xxxpeter,uk

luis,mex

xxxangel,ital

dupont,fran

xxxcharles,belg

...

more lines with xxxname

...

How can I delete key/value what contain (or start) with xxx in key. This is what I got so far:

```
public void Deletekeyxxx() {
    final SharedPreferences.Editor sped = sharedPreferences.edit();     
    if(sped.contains("xxx")){
      sped.remove(sped.contains("xxx"));
    }
    sped.commit();
 }
```

---

**Works! Thank you Ben P.**

```
public void Deletekeyxxx() { 
    final SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPrefsEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    Map<String, ?> allEntries = sharedPreferences.getAll();
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        if (key.contains("xxx")) {
           sharedPrefsEditor.remove(key);
        }
      sharedPrefsEditor.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep it simple, iterate through all present keys in preferences and delete if it contains/start with your searching key

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`SharedPreferences.getAll()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getAll()) to retrieve a `Map<String,?>`, and then use `Map.keySet()` to iterate over the keys. Maybe something like this:

```
private void removeBadKeys() {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Mypref", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

    for (String key : preferences.getAll().keySet()) {
        if (key.startsWith("xxx")) {
            editor.remove(key);
        }
    }

    editor.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sharedPreferences.getAll()` to get all the key/value references on your shared preferences and then iterate through them and remove the ones you want.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
Map<String, ?> allEntries = sharedPreferences.getAll();
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    if (key.contains("xxx")) {
        editor.remove(key);
    }
    editor.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly remove key-value using following lines, no need to do string check

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Mypref", 0);
preferences.edit().remove("shared_pref_key").commit();
```